# Sorting an array inside PHP by element of that array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have an array in my PHP controller like this:

```
$expired_brands = array();
```

And items inside the array like this:

```
array_push($expired_brands,$brand);
```

Where $brand contains a date like this:

```
$brand['endDate'];
```

My question here is, is there any way for me to sort this array without using query... Is there some function in PHP that can sort the elements based on their values inside the array?

So to note: I'd like to sort the elements inside the array by its endDate like this:

```
$brand['endDate'];
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `usort()` and then just get the timestamp and use it as comparison.

Comment: Hi @Rizer123 can you please show me the link to the duplicate question ??

Comment: Right under "This question already has an answer here:" is the link.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere lol

Comment: Try to reload the page; See: http://imgur.com/8iuzv4c

Comment: Okay I see it..But ugh looks complex ... lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113403/discussion-between-perkes456-and-rizier123).